# Postgresql: replace part of string on update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 5000 plus records where I need to remove part of the value of a field

In all cases, the part I wish to remove is "Job Description - "

Hence update so that "Job Description - Doctor" becomes "Doctor"

So (I guess) I am looking to

```
UPDATE mytable 
    SET myfield = {some regex}
```

where myfield like '%Job Description - %'

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is as follows:

```
UPDATE mytable 
  SET myfield = REPLACE(myfield, 'Job Description - ','');
```